# Ajax request to get data from php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been researching on how to make an Ajax request and came up with this:

```
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "http://localhost:888...-files/test.php";
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   var return_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = return_data;
   }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

I saved this script as a file under: http://localhost:888...ascript/test.js <-- I have tested other scripts saved at this location and they work perfectly fine. My php file contains the following data (it is named "test.php"):

```
<?php
echo(rand(10,100));
?>
```

After I make the request to the php file which should display a random number according to the php code, my html looks like this:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<body onload="ajax_post()">     <------ Here you can see that I have called the function which executes the AJAX Request after the page has loaded.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:888...ascript/test.js"></script>
</body>
</div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I keep refreshing the page and nothing appears. Does it have to do with my php code? Perhaps my Ajax request is wrongly structured? In terms of  Ajax request, I have tried "GET" and "POST" as well and still nothing happens. I am new at Ajax and the might syntax my not make sense... Thank you in advance for the support.

Regards!!

Comment: You are calling the `ajax_post()` in the `body` element, yet you include the script that has that function after. Also, there is no need to put the whole url as the script's src. Instead, you could just write `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/test.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thanks @kidA , I have used other onload properties, placed the script afterwards and they still work. Is the syntax of my Ajax request correct?

Comment: Your syntax seems to be ok as far as I see. Probably the ajax request does not reach the url you set. What output do you get in network flow for the ajax call when the page is loaded?

Comment: I get nothing. No output is produced. NB: I use wordpress which is based on php and my local server runs with latest version of php.

Comment: What are the values for request url and status code in the headers tab?

Comment: Aaaah I just saw I have got nothing in the headers tabs. What variable would I put there in order to load the php code using Ajax?

Comment: Right click and select `Inspect Element` in a Chrome browser. Choose `Network` from the tabs that are going to appear. The next time you are going to reload the page you are going to see on the left bar in the network tab the elements needed for that page loading one by one. Click on the php file that is hit by the POST request - in your case something that ends n `...-files/test.php`. There is no way you have no values for status code and request url in the Header tab if you follow these steps.

Comment: It appears in my source code. But what happens is that the php does not get process. The status is OK and the browser gets information but does not display a random number, instead it gets the entire function:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some html to the php file and everything loads except the php file (php appeared as a comment). Then, I came up with the idea to compare the php file I created with the other php files on my local server. I identified a little difference. The other php files do not close the php, i.e. `<?php echo 'Hello World';` without putting `?>` at the end, and now it works. My php file looks like this:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
```

I also simplified my script, making my structure look like follows:

```
<div id="demo"><div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#demo').load('http://localhost:8888/...php-files/test.php');
});
</script>
```

I used JQuery .load() property as it is simpler than the normal script (same principle).